# getResourceAsStream working in eclipse, but not when run as applet in browser

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, applet, getresource

I have an applet that needs to load saved data from a local text file that is in the eclipse package with the .java files. For use in this questions its name is "saveData.txt".

When I run the applet through eclipse, everything works perfectly. However, once I jar it up (making sure the txt file and .classpath files are included) and put it onto a website, the applet fails to load. I am getting an error of Unknown source on my InputStreamReader. I have included my code for loading and saving below. The error comes on the creation of the InputStreamReader Line.

Any Ideas where I screwed up?

`private ArrayList loadLocations() throws IOException{
        ArrayList locations = new ArrayList();
        InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("\saveData.txt");`

```
            ;; BELOW LINE is where exception is thrown
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    mInputStream = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line = mInputStream.readLine();

    while (line != null && !(line.equals(""))) {
        locations.add(new Location(line));

        line = mInputStream.readLine();
    }
    if (mInputStream != null)
        mInputStream.close();   

    Collections.sort(locations);

    return locations;
}

private void saveLocations() throws IOException {
    try {
        mOutputStream = new PrintWriter(new File(getClass().getResource("\\saveData.txt").toURI()));
    }
    catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ;
    for (Location l : locations) {
        mOutputStream.print(l.getRawListing()+ "\n");
    }


    if (mOutputStream != null)
        mOutputStream.close();

}
```

Full Error details (when run in browser)

```
Java Plug-in 1.6.0_24
Using JRE version 1.6.0_24-b07 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\Ross
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to 
----------------------------------------------------


java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.sun.deploy.util.DeployAWTUtil.invokeAndWait(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.runOnEDT(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.(Unknown Source)
    at listings.listings.loadLocations(listings.java:624)
    at listings.listings.setup(listings.java:667)
    at listings.listings.(listings.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$12.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't Java looking in the Jar file for this?  Is your text file loaded as a resource in the Jar file?

Comment: yes, the saveData.txt is being exported into the jar file.

Comment: And saveData.txt is located with the class files?  I would think that you'd have more problems with trying to write to a resource than trying to read from one.  Which line is throwing the exception, and can you post the exact text of the exception as an edit to your original post?

Comment: getResource and getResourceAsStream expect forward slashes for one thing.

Comment: I may be a huge dumbass, i need one more level on the file path and forward slashes (thanks MeBigFatGuy). let me try Jaring it up again

Comment: And thanks to Hovercraft Full Of Eels, i realized my filepath was wrong from your post. I'd like to give one of you credit for answering my question though (but it doesn't appear I can do that for a comment)

Comment: Thanks will do.  Glad to help on this.